# Map or match a Scalaz.EitherT

Tags: scala, scalaz, twitter-finagle

I have this for-comprehension:

```
 val seq = for {
        accessToken <- EitherT(getAccessToken(code))
        data <- EitherT(getDefaultData(accessToken))
        user <- EitherT(mapUser(data.getResponseBody))
      } yield {
        if (Users.getUserByOriginId(user.origin).isEmpty) {
          Users.register(user)
          OAuthProvider.redirectToSignUp(user.userId.get)
        } else {
          OAuthProvider.redirectToAuthentication(user.userId.get)
        }
      }
```

It chains `com.twitter.util.Future` operations, each of the methods returning a `Future[\/[InvalidResponse, CorrectResponse]]`

I now want to `map` or `match` over the result.

```
val response = seq.run match {
    case x.left => "something"
    case y.right => "something else"
}// this syntax is invalid
```

What is the correct syntax to `match` between `left` and `right`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The match syntax is

```
val response = seq.run.map{fut => fut.match {
      case -\/(left) => "something"
      case \/-(right) => "something else"
  }
}
```

You can also do fold/catamorphism on the EitherT:

```
seq.fold(something, somethingElse)
```

where `something` takes a value of left type & returns a value of type X and `somethingElse` takes a value of right type and returns a value of type X. The result of the entire expression being Future[X]

Comment: I would definitely go for fold !

Answer (score -3):

what about using a Validation? then it would be

```
{
 case Success(s) => do s
 case Failure(f) => do f 
}
```

i think in your case, it will be

```
{
  case Right(r) => do r
  case Left(l) => do l
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the first downvoter, but this just isn't an answer. `Validation` is a different type with different semantics, and `Right` and `Left` aren't constructors for `\/`.

Comment: sure, but in your case, you are using it exactly as a validation, so you could convert and use Success/Failure